# Wireshark (WinPCap) does not see Intel X520-DA2 10 GbE NIC teaming intermittently

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wireshark, intel, network-teaming, winpcap

I am running a team of two 10 GigE ports on Intel X520-DA2 network card.  They work well in tandem and achieve the desired throughput.  However, I see an intermittent issue whereby WireShark and my own application (using WinPCap) only show the underlying ports, failing to recognize the team adapter.

Details: Intel 17.4 NIC drivers on Windows Server 2008 R2 with all patches.  HP DL370 G6 server. RSS enabled on Intel both underlying Intel NICs.

The exact error:
    Unable to open the adapter (rpcap://\Device\NPF_{401D5903-16E7-41DC-8484-5D96765B9692}). failed to set hardware filter to promiscuous mode

Cross-posted on [WireShark site](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/16751/wireshark-winpcap-does-not-see-intel-x520-da2-10-gbe-nic-teaming-intermittently).

Comment: I heard that if you say his name three times, @GeraldCombs shows up to answer Wireshark questions here.

Comment: The fact that he's a user here is the coolest thing.

Comment: Sometimes in the driver properties under device manager there is an option for allowing promiscuous mode. Perhaps this is a hardware limitation though.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff I checked in the Intel configuration sheets, but did not find anything related to this.

Comment: Is that card a "CNA" style card? Can you partition it at all?

Comment: I see that it is... and suspect your answer may lie there. Perhaps promiscuous mode can only be enabled on a child?

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff How would I do that?